# macOS : PyQt5 conflict with opencv-python

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, opencv

I wrote a program that uses pyqt5 and opencv-python to capture video from the camera, but when I run the program I get :

```
objc[35814]: Class QCocoaPageLayoutDelegate is implemented in both /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11439c5c0) and /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x11576c468). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35814]: Class QCocoaPrintPanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11439c638) and /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x11576c4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35814]: Class QCocoaApplicationDelegate is implemented in both /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11439c340) and /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x117b03b88). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35814]: Class QNSApplication is implemented in both /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11439c2f0) and /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x117b03bd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35814]: Class QCocoaMenuLoader is implemented in both /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11439c2a0) and /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x117b03d18). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35814]: Class QNSImageView is implemented in both /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11439c660) and /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x117b03e08). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35814]: Class QNSStatusItem is implemented in both /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11439c6b0) and /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x117b03e58). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[35814]: Class QNSOpenSavePanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11439c480) and /Users/username/python_env/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x117b03ef8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

cv2 and pyqt5 conflict.

The OS is macOS High Sieera, the version of python is 3.5.2, a virtual environment was created with venv, and "pip install pyqt5", "pip install opencv-python" was executed in that, and the library was installed.

In ubuntu and windows it works normally without error, but only mac doesn't work.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the code to better understand this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my code. Its because of the conflict of the opencv and pyqt5. I was able to solve the problem by Installing a headless version of the opencv

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found two solutions

1, choose low version of opencv-python( I choose opencv-python 4.1.2.30 to solve this problem)

2, choose opencv-python-headless

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).